# PHP Code with POST to get data from MYSQL returns undefined Variable

Tags: php, android, post, mysqli, httpurlconnection

I am using PHP file to send variable of android application to MYSQLi request and return the output in shape of string.

I tried many php codes especially the below one (as I read MSQLI doesn't permit using variable directly in quires for security). but the app reads the output as MYSQL error"undifined Variable in Line 4" and I can't find the solution.

Edit: PHP Code edited but still has the same error.
PHP Code:

```
<?php
require "init.php";
$coresite = $_POST["selectedcoresite"]="";
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT Cabinet_Row FROM cabinets WHERE Core_Site=?");
$stmt -> bind_param("s", $_POST['selectedcoresite']);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> bind_result($result);
$stmt -> fetch();
echo '("'.implode('", "', $result).'")';
?>
```

The Code android code is working as I get output at the end but this is the code:

```
if (operator.equals("GetRow")){
            try {
                String selectedcoresite = params [1];
                Log.v(TAG, "GetRow Verbose");
                URL url = new URL(rowsurl);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8" ));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode(selectedcoresite,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();

                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS, "iso-8859-1"));
                while ((line2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    row+= line2;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                IS.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return row;
```

I need the output to be in the form of string like
"101","103","105","120" ... ETC

thanks for your support.

Comment: Which line is getting the error? What variable does it say is undefined?

Comment: Where do you assign the variable `$mysqli`?

Comment: `$_POST["selectedcoresite"];` what do you expect that line to do?

Comment: @Barnar, line 4 has the error. I am not familiar with PHP that is why I thought mysqli --> will define the variable.

Comment: @Farkie, this takes the value of my output stream of my android app.

Comment: As I can see you have `$coresite` variable with value of `$_POST['selectedcoresite']` and equals to `empty string`, can you try to bind `$coresite` instead of `$_POST['selectedcoresite']` ? and define `$result` variable before bind it. If I remember correct `bind`-function using refer-link to the variable and may be declaring it before bind will save you from similar error.